# Error in --rosdep-install

Tags: slam, navigation, rosdep, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
When I try this code "rosmake --rosdep-install rgbdslam" it gives the following error.

rosmake: error: no such option: --rosdep-install

I installed rosdep using this command ."sudo apt-get install python-rosdep"

Then I found that   '--rosdep-install' option is available in ROS Electric and earlier. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS groovy. How can I solve this?Can somebody please help?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71326/error-in---rosdep-install/) by [Cham](https://answers.ros.org/users/5147/cham/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-08-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-08-05**:
What instructions are you following?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can call rosdep directly.  The change is simply that rosmake no longer will call rosdep for you.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cham](https://answers.ros.org/users/5147/cham/) on 2013-08-05**:
Thank you. I got it :)